# C++/WinRT ContentDialog template

Tags: c++-winrt

I have just started to study C++/WinRT programming and am trying to create a ContentDialog from the template. Using C++/WinRT v2.0.190506.1

The "Add new item -> Content Dialog" wizard creates files with a lot of errors:

[image]
[image]

The code resembles C++/CX.

Can anyone please provide a valid C++/WinRT template code?

Comment: I did that to demonstrate the errors

Comment: For that purpose you should check (and add here) what the errors are, instead of just dumping the whole thing.

Comment: James Z, what is the sense of listing the erros (there are 20+ of them) if the template uses some different language (C++/CX instead of standard C++17)?

Comment: What's the sense of adding whole code as a picture without the errors? But I don't care, do what you want

Comment: My intention was to show that there are hatches, refs and other non standard C++ elements in the code, which means that the entire template code needs to be rewritten, not just some individual errors fixed.

Comment: @jam: The code doesn't matter, neither do the error messages. This question is asking how to generate a `ContentDialog` for use by C++/WinRT. The wizards built into Visual Studio generate C++/CX (which isn't C++). Posting the errors from a C++ compiler when it's fed something that isn't C++ isn't useful.